# (Generation has thrown an exception:) has no explanation behind it and I have tried all the fixes I could find

Tags: rigging, error, rigify

[image]

All I want to do is pose this character with rigify and nothing I try fixes this. when I try to "generate rig" it always makes a new rig that is 1 bone at the feet and then gives me the error code `Generation has thrown an exception:`.

If anyone has an idea on how to fix this I would greatly appreciate it.

[image]

Comment: I hope this is how you upload a blender file [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=0ADBPORx" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/0ADBPORx/)

Comment: You have duplicate vertices.  Select the teddy bear, go into edit mode, type "M" and select "by distance" from the popup menu.  But you also seem to have modified the metarig.  Rigify doesn't work well when you do that, and that's causing the exception.  Try again with a clean metarig.

Comment: ah dang. thank you I shall try again